# Convergence of Hermitian inner product in $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: fourier-analysis

In the vector space $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ over $\mathbb{C}$ (i.e. the set of all two-sided infinite sequence of complex numbers such that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |a_n^2| < \infty$) why is it guaranteed that the inner product $(A, B) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a_n \overline{b_n}$ is absolutely convergent?

Comment: Do you know about the **Cauchy-Schwarz inequality**? That may be helpful for you.

Comment: Ah got it, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! $\ddot{\smile}$

Comment: Also, $2|a_n||b_n| \le |a_n|^2+|b_n|^2$, which follows from $(|a_n|-|b_n|)^2 \ge 0$.